# Pandas - Check if value from a column exists in any index of a MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I got a MultiIndex dataframe called df with two indexes (index1, index2). I want to search by row to check if the value in the Column exists in any of the multi-index.

This is what df looks like

```
                Column
index1 index2
   a     b         b
         c         e
         d         c
   f     e         e
         g         e
         h         f
```

In terms of the boolean value, this is what I want to generate in order to filter the dataframe

```
                Column
index1 index2
   a     b       True
         c       False
         d       False
   f     e       True
         g       False
         h       True (f is in the index1)
```

The final output should be like this:

```
                Column
index1 index2
   a     b         b
   f     e         e
         h         f
```

Is there any good practice to handle this?

Comment: I'm wondering if the 'c' and the second 'e' should be true, too? Since they are in index2.

Comment: No, what I am trying to achieve right here is not looking at the indexes as a whole but looking at them by each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html) with [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for compare all levels and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if at least one level is match:

```
df1 = df[df.index.to_frame().eq(df['Column'], axis=0).any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
              Column
index1 index2       
a      b           b
f      e           e
       h           f
```

Or use list comprehension with `in` for test if exist value of column in index:

```
df1 = df[[v in k for k, v in df['Column'].items()]]
print (df1)
              Column
index1 index2       
a      b           b
f      e           e
       h           f
```

Comment: What a neat and beautiful solution. Thank you so much! I forgot to mention that I have tried this approach : df[df.index.to_frame().isin(df['neighbor']).any(axis=1)] However, this always generates the ValueError: cannot compute isin with a duplicate axis. Could you also explain why this is not working in this scenario?

Comment: @JerryLin If check how working isin it test all values membership, in another words test if all values from column exist in levels of MultiIndex. So output is like True, True, False, True, True, True

Btw, your solution should working if use `df[df.index.to_frame(index=False).isin(df['neighbor'].tolist()).any(axis=1).to_numpy()]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `get_level_values`:

```
m1 = df.index.get_level_values('index1') == df['Column']
m2 = df.index.get_level_values('index2') == df['Column']
out = df[m1|m2]
print(out)

# Output
              Column
index1 index2       
a      b           b
f      e           e
       h           f
```

**Generic way**

```
import numpy as np

out = df[np.logical_or.reduce([list(lvl) == df['Column'] for lvl in zip(*df.index)])]
print(out)

# Output
              Column
index1 index2       
a      b           b
f      e           e
       h           f
```

Comment: The get_levels_values is a good approach; however, it seems harder to manage if there are more layers of multi-index. As for the generic numpy solution, I will say it takes a few more steps to achieve the same result compared to @jezrael answer.  Still, thank you for sharing these methods.